# Copying the Google+ blue arrow advert

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I really liked [this Google+ advert](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7KewDzuyCg). Clean, elequant, somewhat subtle.

How can I reproduce it? Ideally, just CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: The simplest way to do something similar would be to position the image absolutely and fade it in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the animated image, you can create it in Flash and convert it to an animated .gif. For displaying it, you really only need to set it as a background image and you should be pretty much set.